# Magento 1.7 - getting cart items for a specific customer

Tags: magento

I really need to check what products (or only if any) a specific customer has in cart.

I want to create a cron task to check if customer has opened cart older than for example 2 days and then send him a mail with reminder message. I've got an array with customers:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$customers = array();
foreach ($collection as $customer) {
    $customers[] = $customer->toArray();
```

But for two days I can't find the way to check the cart items for each of them.
I tried:

```
foreach ($customers as $item) {

   $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($item['entity_id']);

   if ($quote) {
       $collection = $quote->getItemsCollection(false);
   }
   else {
       echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("test")</script>';
   }
   print_r($collection);
   foreach ($collection as $tmp)
       echo $tmp->getQty();
}
```

I tried also many more but nothing work for me :/
I also don't know how to print returned items, every field in the array is protected.

Please help if You can or You only think You can ;) Google didn't help with it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using Magento Community since Enterprise already has an abandoned cart reminder. If you have access to Enterprise you can find the code here: Enterprise_Reminder_Model_Rule_Condition_Cart::_prepareConditionsSql($customer, $website)
This method creates a raw sql using magento Resource read adapter and adds different conditions to verify if cart is abandoned or not you can see some of them below ( don't forget to check quote.updated_at )

```
$select = $this->getResource()->createSelect();
$select->from(array('quote' => $table), array(new Zend_Db_Expr(1)));
...
$select->where('quote.is_active = 1');
$select->where($this->_createCustomerFilter($customer, 'quote.customer_id'));
...
```

I hope this excerpt helps gives you a start, I don't know if I can post the code from Enterprise here.

Comment: Thanks very much I don't have access to magento enterprice but when You called it "abandoned cart reminder" I looked for some plugin and I found it, I think. 
I have to try it, but thanks very much.